# Disable group selection in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How to disable group selection in Fabric.js and leave single objects selectable one at a time? With group selection I mean selecting multiple objects using eg. SHIFT+Click.

Answer (score 44):

you can easily achieve this with

```
  canvas.selection = false; // disable group selection
```

if you want it on individual object

```
  rect.set('selectable', false); // make object unselectable
```

Comment: Leaves this single objects selectable? AFAIK this disables all selections.

Comment: @Timo: No, this disables the selection when you press and hold the left mouse button and then move the mouse. You will see that nothing happens, i.e. the selection box does not get visible.

Comment: On Fabric JS version 4 this doesn't disable more than one object being selection when a user uses SHIFT+Click.

Answer (score 9):

Disable group selection via selection listener canvas method (in my opinion the best way)

```
canvas.on('selection:created', (e) => {
  if(e.target.type === 'activeSelection') {
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
  } else {
    //do nothing
  }
})
```

Comment: Why is this better than `canvas.selection = false`?

Comment: You wouldn't have to jump between turning canvas selection on or off on the whole canvas throughout interaction of your app directly. This can be case by case depending on the object you are interacting with. I find it to be a bit more targeted.

Answer (score 1):

@CQ Smooth's answer was close to my requirements, thanks. But I needed the event to be fired when you select one object first, then add another via shift+click:

```
  canvas.on({
      'selection:updated': e => {
        const activeSelection = e.target
        if (activeSelection) {
           canvas.discardActiveObject();
        }
      }
  })
```

You can see the solution working at: https://app.collagemaker.uk/create